# Does Rails index existing records when running an index migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, rails-migrations

When adding an index to an existing column in Rails:

```
add_index :users, :some_id
```

and then running the migrations:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Are all pre-existing records/columns automatically indexed?
Database used is Postgres.

Comment: Just a note: As index creation is a blocking operation and may lock the table for writes till the index gets created you may want to do this judiciously if the table is very large. Ref: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-createindex.html#SQL-CREATEINDEX-CONCURRENTLY

Comment: @AlokSwain Thats a good one!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it does. It calls postgres [`CREATE INDEX`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html) that creates an index and fills it with existing data.